# Django Rest Framework: Calling Internal API from External API

Tags: rest, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have to call an internal API from an external API in given Django Rest Framework.
When a user clicks on some button(`'View Calendar'`) in Front-end( which is in Angular), an API endpoint (`'/viewCalendar/'`) of DRF is called. This is the external API endpoint.
In the `views.py` for the endpoint of `/viewCalendar/`, I need to write the code such a way that it will call another API (say, `'/commandExecForCalendar/'`) which will actually execute the method and will return the output. This output will be further be responded to front-end by external API. 
Both External and Internal API reside in same DRF project.

```
 myDRFProj/
   commandExecApp/
       views.py -------- > this  CBV works for internal calls
       .
       .
   externalAPIApp/
       views.py  -------- > this CBV handles API call from front-end and it will call the API for internal calls

   mydrfproj/
       settings.py
       urls.py ---------- > holds both external and internal API endpoints
```

*urls.py*

```
 url(r'commandExecForCalendar', commandExecAppView.cmdExcFrCalendar.as_view()),
 url(r'viewCalendar', externalAPIAppView.extApiCall.as_view()),
```

So, how to write those two views such that external view will send the request data to internal and get the result from it to Response to front-end?

Comment: This is where a helper method or package is useful.  You can move the main implementation of the code to be called from multiple locations, while keeping the REST API endpoints the same.  So, if you abstract out the code in `commandExecApp` to a helper method or class, and import that module to be used by `externalAPIApp`, you'll get what you need without needing to explicitly make a HTTP request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending of the complexity of your API you may be able design the `externalAPIApp` views in such a way that they sub-class the `CommandExecApp` CBVs.

I've attempted this in the past but hit roadblocks due to the function signatures and return types of the DRF class based views. This isn't uncommon when extending functionality via inheritance (vs composition) within an application.

That said, there are a few ways to approach this:

**API Gateway**

Design the `externalAPIApp` to act as a gateway web-service that essentially passes HTTP requests through to the `commandExecApp` API via HTTP.

You can look at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library for the "client" requests that `externalAPIApp` will make to the `commandExecApp`.

**Shared domain module**

Consider there are three major components to the application:

1. External API: isolated API that is accessible to and authorizes external clients.
2. Internal API: an isolated API that is accessible to and authorizes internal clients.
3. Domain module: a self-contained Python module that handles all interaction with Django ORM.

**Tradeoffs**

There are pros and cons to both.

The Gateway approach introduces some latency associated with additional (local) network requests. On the other hand the DRF offers developer time-saving features/components that lend themselves to being tightly-coupled with the domain logic.

The shared domain module offers greater separation of concerns but likely involves writing and testing more code up front.

Ultimately it's an architectural decision to make with an understanding of your development schedule, technology roadmap, the people involved, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable opinion. What I did here: External API calls the Internal API with `requests`.method() .To send the request.data, I used json.dumps(reeust.data) . And when internal API responded the data was converted from dict to  json().  However, it was a testing purpose approach.  Also did it with creating object of internal class. Both worked.